# Chrome Extension $.post request Callback fails

Tags: jquery, json, google-chrome-extension

I have a Google Chrome Extension.  In my Content.js I am performing a POST request which operates fine except for I do not get a callback response when json data is returned.

Here is my call

```
$.post(("http://localhost:4089/i3cloud.com/ilinklogemailnoimap.ashx?opensocial_owner_id=" + ownerId),
        '{"data":"' + dataString + '"}' ,
        function () {
            alert('response');
            },
        "json");
```

it calls an ashx handler that returns with the following response from the handler.

```
context.Response.Write("{'user_exists' : true, 'result' : 'Success'}")
```

I do not get the callback...

If the response is empty I get the response and my Alert is called.

```
context.Response.Write("")
```

Have I got the format of the JSON response correct?

I am using jquery-2.0.2

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not sure if this would cause the problem, but JSON keys and string values are supposed tobe double quoted. So, try changing the response to: `'{"user_exists" : true, "result" : "Success"}'`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I ended up with the following working "[{\"user_exists\":\"true\",\"result\":\"Success\"}]"

Comment: OK, just keep in mind that (as far as JSON is concerned) `"true"` and `true` are different values (the former is of type 'string', while the latter is of type 'boolean').

Comment: Good point - thanks [{\"user_exists\":true,\"result\":\"Success\"}] would be the correct string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work with the following:

```
"[{\"user_exists\":\"true\",\"result\":\"Success\"}]"
```

I generated the json with the following:

```
 JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    responseList = new List<responseItem>();
    responseItem ri = new responseItem();
    ri.user_exists = "true";
    ri.result = "Success";
    responseList.Add(ri);
    context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(responseList));
```